# Representing 2D Plot and 3D Plot next to each other, sharing $z$-axis

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, grid-layouts

I have the following code

```
Posvec = {Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]], 
Cos[\[Theta]]};
Func = Function[{z}, -z^2];
P1 = ParametricPlot[{ Func[Posvec[[3]]], Posvec[[3]]}, {\[Theta], 
0, \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Full, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[-x]], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False];
L1 = ParametricPlot3D[
Posvec, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Theta], 0.01, 0.9999 \[Pi]},  
Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
ViewVector -> {{100, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, PlotPoints -> {50, 50}, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, \[Phi], \[Theta]}, Hue[z^2]], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False];
GraphicsGrid[{{P1, L1}}, Alignment -> Center]
```

This first creates 2 plots like this

[image]

and this

[image]

The last line then creates an image of both plots next to each other. Like this

[image]

Now, technically the color plot on the ball and the parabola represent the same value. I would like them to either share the z-axis or at least have the ball and the plot the same height. I really tried, but don't seems to be very successful! As a second thing it would be really nice if one could bring them closer together.

I would be really happy about help

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way is to also plot the curve in 3D.

```
posvec = {Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ]};
movevec = {1.5, 0, 0};
func = Function[{z}, -z^2];

curve = ParametricPlot3D[{func[posvec[[3]]], 0, 
    posvec[[3]]}, {θ, 0, π}, PlotRange -> All, 
   AspectRatio -> Full, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[-x]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False];
sphere = ParametricPlot3D[
   posvec + movevec, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {θ, 0, π}, 
   Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, PlotPoints -> {50, 50}, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, ϕ, θ}, Hue[z^2]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False];

Show[{curve, sphere}, ViewPoint -> Front, 
 ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 3}, {-2, 4}, Automatic}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image: Method 1]

Alternatively, you can manually set all the relevant options (`PlotRange, ImageMargins, ImagePadding, SphericalRegion`), and combine with `Row` or `GraphicsRow`.

```
curve = ParametricPlot[{func[posvec[[3]]], posvec[[3]]}, {\[Theta], 
    0, \[Pi]}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[-x]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> {{-1, 0}, {-1, 1}}, 
   ImageSize -> {150, 200}, ImageMargins -> 0, ImagePadding -> 20, 
   AspectRatio -> Full];

sphere = ParametricPlot3D[
   posvec, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, Axes -> False, 
   Boxed -> False, PlotPoints -> {50, 50}, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, \[Phi], \[Theta]}, Hue[z^2]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ViewPoint -> Front, 
   ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
   ImageSize -> {200, 200}, SphericalRegion -> False, 
   ImageMargins -> 0, ImagePadding -> 20];

Row[{curve, sphere}]
```

[image: Method 2]

Comment: Genius!!!!!!!!!

Comment: But what if the $x$-axes need to scale differently?

Comment: Well, in that case, you can manually transform (scale) the object by multiplying the $x$ coordinate.

Comment: @jabru, I have also added a second method, which is perhaps more suitable to your needs.